# How to read from console in "not main" process

Tags: input, concurrency, erlang

How to read from stdin in new process? I can put line and print it only in main process. Should I pass to get_line console device or sth similar or it's not possible?

My code:

```
-module(inputTest).
-compile([export_all]).

run() ->
  Message = io:get_line("[New process] Put sth: "),
  io:format("[New process] data: ~p~n", [Message]).


main() ->
  Message = io:get_line("[Main] Put sth: "),
  io:format("[Main] data: ~p~n", [Message]),
  spawn(?MODULE, run, []).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `main/0` process spawns `run/0` and then immediately exits. You should make `main/0` wait until `run/0` is finished. Here's how you can do that:

```
-module(inputTest).
-compile([export_all]).

run(Parent) ->
    Message = io:get_line("[New process] Put sth: "),
    io:format("[New process] data: ~p~n", [Message]),
    Parent ! {self(), ok}.

main() ->
    Message = io:get_line("[Main] Put sth: "),
    io:format("[Main] data: ~p~n", [Message]),
    Pid = spawn(?MODULE, run, [self()]),
    receive
        {Pid, _} ->
            ok
    end.
```

After spawning `run/1` — and note that we changed it to pass our process ID to it — we wait to receive a message from it. In `run/1` once we print to the output, we send the parent a message to let it know we're done. Running this in an `erl` shell produces the following:

```
1> inputTest:main().
[Main] Put sth: main
[Main] data: "main\n"
[New process] Put sth: run/1
[New process] data: "run/1\n"
ok
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I didn't know that main process must be alive to use input functions.